# Extract only date from a date/time field SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have seen different variations of this question before, but haven't seen an answer that works for me. I have a DATE_MODIFIED field that is a date/time field. I want to write a where clause on it and select the date using GETDATE(). That is, I want to be able to select the data for today's date regardless of the time the query is run. Can anyone provide any advice here? I'm still pretty new at this.

```
where DATE_MODIFIED = GETDATE()
```

Comment: `WHERE DATE_MODIFIED >= CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE())`

Comment: `WHERE DATE_MODIFIED >= dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0,getdate()),0)`

Comment: both approaches solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do this

```
WHERE CAST(DATE_MODIFIED AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

And, if you are interested in performance of date checks etc, this is a good read

http://sqlperformance.com/2012/09/t-sql-queries/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-trim-time-from-datetime

Comment: both approaches solved my problem. Thanks!

Comment: Your welcome, I agree that this is a dupe but if your new to SQL then I can why someone may not see that you are just removing the time to compare.